# Configuring a DataTable using CoffeeScript

Tags: jquery, object-oriented, coffeescript

I am working on a simple Rails app. For the `Expense` resource I use a [DataTable](https://www.datatables.net/). So, in my CoffeeScript for this resource I basically do several things:

- initialize the datatabe;
- since I use a custom search field (not the one, provided by DataTables), I add a search function in the table api;
- initialize the [Select2](https://select2.github.io/) plugin;
- check to see if the request is made from a mobile device - if yes -> change the type of an input field to date, otherwise initialize [Datepicker](https://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox)
- submit a from when the date from the datepicker is selected

Here is my code

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.type.order['currency-bg-pre'] = parseCurrency

changeTextInputToDate = (input) ->
  input.each(-> $(@).clone().attr('type', 'date').insertBefore(@)).remove()

dataTableFooterCallback = (row, data, start, end, display) ->
    api = @api()
    total = api.column(1).data().reduce sumCurrency, 0
    $(api.column(1).footer()).html("#{total.toFixed(2)} лв")

initializeDatepicker = (element) ->
  element.datepicker
    autoclose: true
    clearBtn: true
    disableTouchKeyboard: true
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
    orientation: 'top auto'
    todayBtn: true
    todayHighlight: true

initializeDateTable = (element) ->
  element.DataTable
    columns: [
        type: 'date',
        searchable: false
      ,
        type: 'currency-bg'
        searchable: false
      ,
        type: 'string'
      ,
        type: null
        orderable: false
        searchable: false
    ]
    footerCallback: dataTableFooterCallback
    order: [[0, 'desc']]
    paging: false
    dom: 't'

initializeSelect2 = (element) ->
  element.select2
    ajax:
      url: '/tags'
      data:
        (query) ->
          query: query.term
      processResults:
        (data) ->
          results: data
      cache: true
    placeholder: 'Enter tag(s)'
    tags: true
    theme: 'bootstrap'
    tokenSeparators: [',']

isMobile = ->
  check = false
  ((a) ->
    if /(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a) or /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0, 4))
      check = true
    return
  ) navigator.userAgent or navigator.vendor or window.opera
  check

parseCurrency = (amount) ->
  switch typeof amount
    when 'string' then amount.match(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/)[0] * 1
    when 'number' then amount
    else 0

sumCurrency = (a, b) -> parseCurrency(a) + parseCurrency(b)

$ ->
  api = initializeDateTable $('.datatable')

  $('#search').on 'keyup', -> api.search(@value).draw()

  initializeSelect2 $('#expense_tag_list')

  if isMobile()
    changeTextInputToDate $('form input:text')
  else
    initializeDatepicker $('.input-group.date')

  $('.datepicker').on 'change', -> $('form').submit()
```

So what I do is basically this:

- figure out what must happen on the page;
- write the function that does that;
- call it on page ready;

Although I have provided a particular example, I generally write JavaScript/CoffeeScript this way. Would you provide some basic example of how you would reorganize this code. In particular I am interested in using CoffeeScript's classes. Also, at what point does one decide that the code has become too messy and one needs to start using Angular/React etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell you when something like Angular/React will make more sense. It's a cost/benefit question, but they're your costs and your benefits.

I'd say you code is *okay*. In some places it seems overly terse, while in others it's spread out too much. And there are a few places where you perhaps abuse CoffeeScript syntax to the point where it becomes *harder* to read.

There's also a number of things that can just be simplified:

- The `isMobile` function doesn't need to be a function with a nested IIFE and a closure. Just run it:

  ```
  isMobile = do ->
    userAgent = navigator.userAgent or navigator.vendor or window.opera or ""
    /.../.test(userAgent) or /.../.test(userAgent.substr(0,4))
  ```

  Now, `isMobile` is just a boolean value. The `do` keyword means it's evaluated immediately. Note I've also added a `""` fallback for `userAgent` just in case. Since you might call `substr` on `userAgent`, it must be a string, or the script will just fail.
- You `changeTextInputToDate` doesn't actually *change* the inputs, really. It replaces them. But changing them seems much easier:

  ```
  changeTextInputToDate = (inputs) ->
    inputs.each -> $(this).attr type: 'date'
  ```

  (I'm using `this` instead of `@` just because I always think `@` looks weird by itself. I like using it as a prefix for things, but if I'm referring to the `this` object itself, I prefer to use `this`. Just personal preference.)
- In `dataTableFooterCallback` it'd be nicer to fetch the column once, since that's what you need for the expressions. I'd also make the footer callback a nested function in `initializeDataTable`, too. Especially as that function references `@api`, which doesn't make sense except in the context of a data table callback. So there's no reason for the function to float around in a wider scope:

  ```
  initializeDateTable = (element) ->
    footerCallback = ->
      column = @api().column(1)
      total = column.data().map(parseCurrency).reduce (sum, value) -> sum + value
      $(column.footer()).html "#{total.toFixed(2)} лв"

    element.DataTable
      columns: [
        { type: 'date', searchable: false }
        { type: 'currency-bg', searchable: false }
        { type: 'string' }
        { type: null, orderable: false, searchable: false }
      ]
      footerCallback: footerCallback
      order: [[0, 'desc']]
      paging: false
      dom: 't'
  ```

  You'll note a few more changes:

  - I'm using explicit `{` and `}` around objects in the `columns` array, rather than relying solely on whitespace - makes it easier to read, I think.
  - I'm using `map` + `reduce`, rather than doing all the work in the `reduce` callback. This makes for a simpler expression, and eliminates `sumCurrency` completely.
- `parseCurrency` I'd write as

  ```
  parseCurrency = (value) ->
    switch typeof value
      when 'number' then value
      when 'string' then (value.match(/\d+(\.\d+)?/)?[0] or 0) * 1
      else 0
  ```

  The `?[0] or 0` guards against `match` returning `null`. Without the null-coalescing `?` your script just fails as `null[0]` doesn't work.

Finally, I'm not sure I understand these last lines:

```
if isMobile()
  changeTextInputToDate $('form input:text')
else
  initializeDatepicker $('.input-group.date')

$('.datepicker').on 'change', -> $('form').submit()
```

So, if it's a mobile client you change *all* text inputs in *any* form. If it's not, you initialize a datepicker with a completely different - and much more specific - selector. It just reads as "either do this, or do something *completely different*". Why aren't the selectors more similar? I'd imagine it's the same inputs you're dealing with.

And finally, the `change` event listener. That's yet another selector!

So that's confusing.